# Nginx bad gateway 502 with piui

Tags: nginx, raspberry-pi

I got a problem with Nginx, it always shows "502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.2.1"

I am using Nginx on my Raspberry Pi with the software Piui.

Last time I used the pi it worked perfectly, now one month later suddenly it doesn't work. This is weird because I didn't change anything in the configs or in the Pi's system.

Does anyone have an idea?

I followed [the PIUI Tutorial](https://github.com/dps/piui). Accesspoint works, can connect and ping from several devices.

I've searched for information, but can't find the issue.

Comment: Did you check the nginx error log? Sounds like the sofware to which the request shall be proxied is not running.

Comment: To be more specific check if the piui-supervisor is running, if not start it ;)

Comment: the error log doesnt show anything, the file is empty... i will check the piui supervisor as soon as possible

Comment: solved! it was the piui-supervisor... thanks a lot for the fast answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

As posted in the comments: Sounds like the sofware to which the request shall be proxied is not running, check if the piui-supervisor is running.